# window.focus() doesn't work after a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, html, dom, settimeout

I have been trying to make a timer where a new small square shaped window pops up with a clock to set the timer(let's call it myWin)

I have saved myWin from `window.open()` function and `myWin.focus()` doesn't work after 5 seconds of `setTimeout();`

I have tried using `window.opener` for which I had kept the timer code in the opened window. Didn't work at all.

```
//Code for timer

function btn1Click() {
    myWin = window.open('small.html', "", "width=100, height=100"); //small.html contains the dummy clock in it

    setTimerValue(5, myWin); // 5 seconds is the hardcoded time, it can be any positive integer
    console.log("Opened");
}

function setTimerValue(mytime) {
    console.log(myWin);
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(mytime);
        mytime--;

        if (mytime == 0) {
            console.log("I am inevitable...")
            clearInterval(interval);
            myWin.focus(); //doesn't work if the value of time is more than 5 seconds

            console.log("Done");
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

The window that contains small.html should come in focus after the `setTimeout` function finishes it's working

Comment: In Firefox I can't get it to work if the timer is set to more than 1 second

Comment: Found this link: https://javascript.info/popup-windows#popup-blocking It says there is some trust in code that prevents popups. Maybe this trust is used in focusing the popups as well?